# Red-Black-Tree Deletion [Fixing the tree when deleting node has no children]

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

I have a tree-fixing algorithm that performs recoloring and rotations, and I have tested this when the node to be deleted has 2 or 1 children. But once they have no children, I don't know what to do.

Since I'm passing in the node to be removed's children, parent and whether or not that children is a left or right child, this cannot be working if the left and right children is both NULL's (same as no children)

I completely understand insertion for red black trees, but when deleting I cannot grasp the general idea. The code that was provided was from my professor, but really I want to write my own version but I don't understand deletion as much as I do for insertion

```
void RedBlackTree::rbDeleteFixUp (Node* child, Node* parent, bool isRightChild){
    while (child != root && child->isBlack == true){
        //Left child
        if (isRightChild = false){
        //Sibling
            Node* sibling = parent->right;

            if (sibling->isBlack = false){
                sibling->isBlack = true;
                child->parent->isBlack = false;
                child = child->parent;
                leftRotate(child);
                sibling = child->parent->right;
            }
            if (sibling->left->isBlack == true && sibling->right->isBlack == true){
                sibling->isBlack = false;
                child = child->parent;
            }
            else{

                if (sibling->right->isBlack == true){
                        sibling->left->isBlack = true;
                        sibling->isBlack = false;
                        rightRotate(sibling);
                        sibling = child->parent->right;

                        sibling->isBlack = child->parent->isBlack;
                        child->parent->isBlack = true;
                        sibling->right->isBlack = true;
                        child = child->parent;
                        leftRotate(child);
                        child = root;
                }
            }

    }
    else{
        Node* sibling = parent->left;

            if (sibling->isBlack = false){
                sibling->isBlack = true;
                child->parent->isBlack = false;
                child = child->parent;
                rightRotate(child);
                sibling = child->parent->left;
            }
            if (sibling->right->isBlack == true && sibling->left->isBlack == true){
                sibling->isBlack = false;
                child = child->parent;
            }
            else{

                if (sibling->left->isBlack == true){
                        sibling->right->isBlack = true;
                        sibling->isBlack = false;
                        leftRotate(sibling);
                        sibling = child->parent->right;

                        sibling->isBlack = child->parent->isBlack;
                        child->parent->isBlack = true;
                        sibling->left->isBlack = true;
                        child = child->parent;
                        rightRotate(child);
                        child = root;
                }
            }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: If a `Node` has a field `parent`, why do you pass `parent` in as an argument?

Comment: Because when a NULL child is passed on, the parent cannot be read from the attribute